# How to apply Camera bounds with CameraPosition in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I need to use few features of both CameraPosition and CameraBounds, Like my specific requirement is to move the camera on a bearing and tilt it on a few degrees as well as there are other markers on the map which i want to cover while i perform a camera update .

**CameraUpdateFactory** class have two different methods on two different purpose. 
**1) newCameraPosition 2) newLatLngBounds**
But i doubt if i can use both of them simultaneously to get the result i want.

CameraPosition works as below :

```
LatLng current_lat_lng=new LatLng(lat, lon);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(current_lat_lng)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
        .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)                   // Sets the zoom
        .bearing((float)mapHeading)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to a bearing
        .tilt(0)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 0 degrees
        .build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

CameraBounds work as below :

```
final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        if (marker_Searched != null) {
            builder.include(marker_Searched.getPosition());
        }
        if (marker_selected_taxi != null) {
            builder.include(marker_selected_taxi.getPosition());
        }   

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();      
        int padding = 300; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Do anyone have tried any workaround with this ?

Comment: Why don't you just use one after the other?

Comment: @Androiderson : that is creating a jitter effect due to two times camera movement ( one with single position and one with Bounds of position )

Comment: To avoid the jigger, try using `animateCamera` on the second one.

Comment: @Androiderson terrible advice.

Answer (score 0):

Animate your camera to the LatLngBounds with CancellableCallback, then in onFinish get zoom value (map.getCameraPosition().zoom) then apply this value into CameraPosition. It works for me fine.

Comment: A more complete example would be nice.